# Multiple matches in non-greedy XML (Python regex)

Tags: python, regex, xml, greedy

I know this topic is asked a lot but I couldn't find an answer to my question:

In the attached image there are many different buffers, and I wish to match only the buffers that have "Lut" in their names (notice there are 2 matches in the string in the image). The problem I have is that the matches contain also the buffers that come before the one I want.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0fPS.png]

I'm pretty new to regex and still trying to learn as much so any explanation will be appreciated.

Thank you! :)

The string is attached for you comfort (if needed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pimp xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
    <dllPath>C:\ReplayCode\Apps\Pimp</dllPath>
    <buffers>   
    <buffer name="InputMask">
            <width>5120</width>
            <height>3072</height>
            <data>UCHAR</data>
            <channels>1</channels>
            <type>IMG</type>
    </buffer>
    <buffer name="MaskErode">
            <width>5120</width>
            <height>3072</height>
            <data>UCHAR</data>
            <channels>1</channels>
            <type>IMG</type>
    </buffer>
    <buffer name="BlablaLutBla">
            <width>256</width>
            <height>256</height>
            <data>UCHAR</data>
            <channels>1</channels>
            <type>IMG</type>
    </buffer>
    <buffer name="MaskClose">
            <width>5120</width>
            <height>3072</height>
            <data>UCHAR</data>
            <channels>1</channels>
            <type>IMG</type>
    </buffer>
    <buffer name="InputVis">
            <width>5120</width>
            <height>3072</height>
            <data>UCHAR</data>
            <channels>3</channels>
            <type>IMG</type>
    </buffer>   
        <buffer name="AddMaskEdge">
            <width>5120</width>
            <height>3072</height>
            <data>UCHAR</data>
            <channels>1</channels>
            <type>IMG</type>
    </buffer>
    <buffer name="EdgeVis">
            <width>5120</width>
            <height>3072</height>
            <data>UCHAR</data>
            <channels>3</channels>
            <type>IMG</type>
    </buffer>       
        <buffer name="GrayEdge">
            <width>5120</width>
            <height>3072</height>
            <data>UCHAR</data>
            <channels>1</channels>
            <type>IMG</type>
    </buffer>
    <buffer name="EdgeMaskMulThreshold">
            <width>5120</width>
            <height>3072</height>
            <data>UCHAR</data>
            <channels>1</channels>
            <type>IMG</type>
    </buffer>
    <buffer name="MaskMulEdge">
            <width>5120</width>
            <height>3072</height>
            <data>UCHAR</data>
            <channels>1</channels>
            <type>IMG</type>
    </buffer>   
    </buffers>
```

The regex I tried is this:

```
<buffer name=".*?Lut.*?">.*?<\/buffer>
```

And I expected 2 matches:

```
<buffer name="BlablaLutBla">
            <width>256</width>
            <height>256</height>
            <data>UCHAR</data>
            <channels>1</channels>
            <type>IMG</type>
    </buffer>
```

and

```
<buffer name="2ndLutBlabla">
            <width>256</width>
            <height>256</height>
            <data>UCHAR</data>
            <channels>1</channels>
            <type>IMG</type>
    </buffer>
```

Comment: You need a [xml parser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

Comment: @luoluo can't it be done with regex?

Comment: The famous [You can't parse \[X\]HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1099230)

Comment: ok so no regex for me... :)
thanks!
Sorry for asking this again. Was pretty sure it's fairy simple task for regex

Comment: Maybe you should paste the regex you've tired here too. The expected output as well.

Comment: @luoluo I edited the original post. You can see there..

Comment: replace first two `.*?` with `[^"]*`

Comment: @YOU Thanks that worked! Is there a way to use `[^..]*` on a string (not a single char)?
`[^(<buffer)]*` doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Omer, I advise you avoid using regex when parsing (getting values from HTML/XML, too) marked up documents, you might have to fix it sooner or later, and without deep understanding how regex works, you will find yourself in a big trouble. Even `[^;]*$` might quickly cause catastrophic backtracking with larger documents. Use [`xml.etree.ElementTree`, see demo here](https://ideone.com/2k9Vhs).

Comment: @stribizhev does `xml.etree.ElementTree` contain function like re.sub (in order to change the xml file)? That is my main goal in my project..

Comment: Replacing existing values is as easy as [`buffer[0].text = "234"`](https://ideone.com/hhVCoU)

Comment: Ok thanks, I will go learn `xml.etree.ElementTree`

Comment: @Omer: Are you working with an XML file, or XML string? I will post an answer showing how to modify XML attributes and inner texts.

Comment: @stribizhev I use a file, but it's not really a problem to load it into a string (which I do when using regex)

Comment: @Omer: I posted an answer of mine, please have a look and feel free to drop a comment.

Comment: `[^"]*` means any char but not `"`, if you want not `<buffer`, you may use `(?!<buffer)` but it is not same as character not, and regex is only good for throw away task that you need to done within few seconds. if you need to maintain code use real parser like other said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `BeautifulSoup` to parse your tag.

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

input_xml = ''' some xml '''
soup = BeautifulSoup(input_xml, "lxml-xml")
print soup.find_all('buffer', attrs={"name": re.compile('Lut')})
```

If you do not have this installed already:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
pip install lxml
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you  need to manipulate the data inside an XML document, use an XML parser.
An answer above already shows how to instantiate the XML tree, but does not dwell upon the structure modification.

BTW, if you instantiate the XML from a string, use `ET.fromstring`

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
...
xml = "<<YOUR XML STRING>>" 
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
```

Else, when reading from a file:

```
tree = ET.parse('file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

Then, you can use the following replacements (where you can actually use a regex if necessary, because here you will already have to deal with plain, unmarked up text data):

```
for buffer in root.findall("buffers/buffer"): 
    if "Lut" in buffer.get("name"):
        buffer.find('width').text = "100"    # Set inner text of buffer child named 'width'
        buffer[1].text = "125"               # Set the 2nd child inner text
        buffer.set('type', 'MY_TYPE');       # Add an attribute to buffer
```

You can print the updated XML using `.dump()`:

```
print ET.dump(root)                          # Print updated XML
```

Or write an updated DOM to the file (if you are working with a file):

```
tree.write('output.xml')
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/hhVCoU) showing modifications on an XML string.

Comment: Thank you! Great explanation! :)

Comment: I found it difficult to change values of the tree to strings containing '<' and `>`.
For instance:
Changing width to:
`(<ARG LutResolutionWidth>)`
Is there a solution expect using str.replace ?

Comment: [This is how you can do it](https://ideone.com/i3AafU). If `<width>(&lt;ARG LutResolutionWidth&gt;)</width>` is what you need to be in XML, of course.

Comment: Actually I want to replace the `&lt;` / `&rt;` with `<` and `>` respectively

Comment: `&lt;` and `&gt;` are *XML entities* that represent `<` and `>` respectively. If you write `<` directly, the XML will become invalid. `>` can be used but it is not best practice, it will cause lots of trouble later.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use xml parsing in python instead, it is quite easy:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(xml)
for buffer in tree.findall("buffers/buffer"): 
    if "Lut" in buffer.get("name"):
        # do your stuff
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<buffer name="[^"]*Lut[^"]*">.*?<\/buffer>
```

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sO7zY4/1)

In your regex's `<buffer name=".*?Lut`,  it will match from the first `<buffer` to the first `Lut`.(`non-greedy worked.If greedy,it will match the last Lut`)